# How to draw a curve surrounding a detected object in the image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I know in Matlab we can use bwboundaries.m to extract indices of boundaries pixels of an detect object, then use plot.m to draw the curve surrounding the object. In Python environment, how to achieve the same result? Are there any functions or image processing modules for this?

My figure is attached below:

[image]

Where the white region (pixel value 1 and the black background of pixel value 0) is the detected object. I want the object enclosed with a solid curve to indicate the region.

Comment: Just choose your preferred library: [openCV](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_begin/py_contours_begin.html), [Sckit-image](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_contours.html), [Scipy](https://www.garysieling.com/blog/finding-image-boundaries-in-python), and I also think numpy has something for this but I can't seem to find the function ([but look for it nonetheless](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/image_processing/)).

Comment: thanks! I will check these modules

Comment: This may help - it still has cool animation even if it doesn't :-) https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gift_wrapping_algorithm